# Inverse modular exponentation

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruences, cryptography

I want to calculate the inverse of a modular exponentation:

$c \equiv b^e \bmod m \qquad  \mid c,e,m \in \mathbb{N}$

$c, e \text{ and } m$ are known and are big numbers. I know that I can calculate a "compatible" $b$ using

$b \equiv \sqrt[e]{c}$ but then b is not necessarily in $\mathbb{N}$. Taking the modulus into account one can reformulate the above equation

$b \equiv \sqrt[e]{c + i \cdot m} \qquad \mid i \in \mathbb{N}$

Iterating over $i$ will eventually yield a solution but is computationally expensive since I am working with big numbers. Is there a more efficient way to find $b$?

Comment: If so, you could break RSA....

Comment: m is not prime, so if I am able to factorize m I can calculate $b$? $e$ is a very small number (3) in my case

Comment: If you can factor $m$ it’s easy.